# Adding unique items to List or other object

Tags: c#, dictionary, unique

I'm trying to find an efficient way to add unique numerical values to a list. Currently, I am using a `Dictionary<int,int>` object. The first value is a generated number; doesn't matter what it is as long as it's generation can be repeated under identical circumstances. The second item is the original. So, I would have this:

```
Dictionary<int,int> orderedList = new Dictionary<int,int>(MaxNoOfTimes);

for (i = 0; i<MaxNoOfTimes, i++)
{   
    int j = getNewValue();

    retry:
    try
    {
        orderedList.Add(j,i);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {  

        goto retry;
    }
```

And while this works, it seems inelegent and I think it is very slow due to the exception handling. The value for MaxNoOftimes can get to several 1000 (in reality there's no actual limit but more then several 1000 would be rare). Is there a faster way? After I am finished with adding the values to the orderedList I create a SortList from the orderedList.

Comment: Why are you using `i++` twice? What could cause an `ArgumentException`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You get `ArgumentException` when element already exists in the dictionary.

Comment: I would think that a Hashset<Int32> would be what you are looking for.  Its' Add method returns a boolean if it was added to the collection or not.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: you're right, missed that. @Ron: why don't you just check if it exists with [`ContainsKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Are you sure it works? You are not changing `j` which is a key for your entry

Comment: Do you want exactly 'MaxNoOfTimes' different values, or all the different values of the first  'MaxNoOfTimes' calls of `getNewValue()` ?

Comment: sorry about the i++; that was an error. I thought about Hashset but I need two values, one the generated number and the second, the ordinal of it for when they are sorted.  I need MaxNoOfTimes values; the values must be different; doesn't matter by how much. They should be as random as possible (I know, an oxymoron but...pseudo-random looking). I use a key so they are based on a key but the key is bytes and that means 256 values. If I need 1000 of them I need int. Right now, it works as is just fine enough but it is VERY slow. I think that's because of the exception (just a guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
for (i = 0; i<MaxNoOfTimes, i++)
{   
    int j = getNewValue();

    while(orderedList.ContainsKey(j))
    {
        j = getNewValue();
    }

    orderedList.Add(j, i);
}
```

Comment: I'll try it but the only thing I would worry about is the possibility of an infinite while loop.

Comment: Needs a bit more testing but I'd say 99% of the time was due to the exception. Now, it's fast! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Hashset<int> orderedSet = new Hashset<int>();
while(orderedSet.Count < maxNoTimes)
{   
   int j = getNewValue();
   orderedSet.Add(j);
}
```

Since, you said you need the ordinal of each value to, then this is probably what you want when ordering:

```
var orderedDictionary = orderedSet.ToDictionary(i => orderedSet.ToList().IndexOf(i), i => i).OrderBy(i => i.Value);
```